# Should we rename our community bot?

Tags: discussion, user-accounts

Every site has a [community bot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19738/278094) which takes the credit for any server action that needs a user id, such as suggested edits.
There is no need for it to be named "*Community*," we could rename it to anything we like.

I'm proposing "*Francesca*," a name that originally comes from [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12122/why-was-my-non-programming-question-on-stackoverflow-closed#comment22357_12122), and has a long SE tradition (since 2009!).

Also *her* gender has been firmly established on the [main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/245123/278094) to be female.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I know this isn't a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) but I'm going to have to [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) this discussion before it gets too far along.

The [community user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user) is identical on all sites for several reasons.  First, it's the bot taking community actions so the name "community" fits perfectly. Second, we like consistency and renaming it to something specific on Blender would be confusing to a user arriving here from [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) or any of the hundreds of other sites.

While we appreciate your enthusiasm, we don't think it's appropriate to change her name. Plus, you don't want to make the her angry, you won't like her when she is angry.

Comment: ok, I understand. Francesca will remain only in thought.

Comment: Because she's the hulk, thats why. :P